# Why is the orbital velocity tangent to the ellipse?

Tags: kinematics, orbital-motion, vectors, velocity, celestial-mechanics

Why is the orbital velocity tangent to ellipse?

And at perigee and apogee the orbital velocity has velocity tangential to the radius vector joining the planet and the star around which it is revolving

Then why does the planet then continues an elliptical path?

that is why does the length of radius vector decrease when the velocity was perpendicular to the radius vector?

Comment: The velocity is always tangent to the path the body is following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer your question, we first have to understand that a   circular motion is very special. 
In order to obtain a circular motion, the distance $r$ between the sun and the planet must be such that it fulfils $m v^2/r = \gamma m M/r^2$. This yields $r = \gamma M / v^2$. Since it is improbable, that two object pass each another with exactly the correct relationship between relative velocity and distance, the circular motion is improbable.

From this arguments we conclude that planets are most probable following a curve around the sun, which is not a circle. However, which curve do they follow?  As has been shown by Kepler the motion of the planet becomes an ellipse. So let's draw a picture containing a circle and an ellipse: [image: Comparing circle and ellipse]

The picture is drawn such, that the planet flights by the sun with a velocity $v$ which would lead to a circular motion, if the distance would be greater.  Nevertheless, at the two points you mentions, perigee and apogee, the velocity and the radius vector are still perpendicular to each another. Since we know that the circle is the only curve which possesses this property on all its points, we conclude that the velocity and the "radius" vector would fulfil this condition on all points of the ellipse. So the question is, how do we get the velocity of an object?

As you probably know we have $v = \frac{ds}{dt}$ -- this states, that the velocity is the change of traveled distance in the time interval $dt$. However, interpreting it in 3D as a vectorial relationship,  it  also states that the velocity is always tangential to the path travelled by the object. Does this make sense?

Comment: That sun is not at the focus of that ellipse. I don't know where you got that picture, but the closest point on the ellipse to the sun should be the leftmost point; it's not.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The sun should sit in one of the focal points of the ellipse. I draw that pic myself, in order to get the idea across, that the velocity is perpendicular to the radius only at two points.

Answer (score 0):

The question mixes ideas which are clearer when thought about separately.

First, the velocity vector is always tangent to the motion. This is always true, not just for orbits. The velocity vector is (defined as) the difference of positions infinitesimally apart in time, divided by that small time. It has to be along the motion because it come from that motion.

Second: velocity is not acceleration. The acceleration can change the velocity vector, given time, in both direction and magnitude.

For Earth orbits, the force of gravity is causing an acceleration toward that adds a certain amount of velocity toward Earth each second.

In a circular orbit, the satellites velocity has to turn a certain amount per distance to stay on that circle. If it’s all set up right, the satellite is at the right speed to cover that distance in the time gravity needs to make the turn.

If the satellite is moving to slow, gravity provides more turn than needed, and the satellite turns down toward Earth.

And once going down, some of gravities acceleration is along the velocity, so the satellite speeds up too.